# Ginkgo test: How to make sure cleanup code is executed when test failed?

Tags: ginkgo

When `Expect()` fails in the `It()` statement, the `AfterEach()` won't be executed.

Is there a way to always execute some code no matter `It()` succeeds or fails? (just like Jave's finally())